# subscribing to custom message type

Tags: ros, callback, custom-message, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a custom message type. I am able to successfully publish it with the topic name "topic".

```
int8 seq_id
std_msgs/Header timestamp
int8 frame_id
float64 myheight
float64 mywidth
int16 step_value
sensor_msgs/Image my_left
sensor_msgs/Image my_right
```

is my custom message.

I created a new package. I want to subscribe to the node publishing "topic".

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

        std::cout << "hello disparity" << std::endl;
    
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("mycustomtopic",1000,chatterCallback);
    
        std::cout << "after subscription disparity" << std::endl;
    
        ros::spin();
        
        std::cout << "after spin disparity" << std::endl;
    
        return 0;
}
```

is my main function.

```
void chatterCallback(const swahana_v2::rectified_imageConstPtr &msg){
    std::cout << "checker " << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

is my callback function written in the same node.

and the output is

```
hello disparity

after subscription disparity

^Cafter spin disparity
```

following is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(compute_disparity)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rectifier

  roscpp

  rospy

  std_msgs

  swahana_v2

  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(hsvgmmN src/hsvgmmN.cpp)

target_link_libraries(hsvgmmN ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(hsvgmmN compute_disparity_generate_messages_cpp)

target_link_libraries(hsvgmmN ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries (hsvgmmN elas viso ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

find_package(message_generation)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)

add_message_files(

  DIRECTORY ../swahana_v2/msg

  FILES rectified_image.msg
)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS swahana_v2)

add_dependencies(hsvgmmN swahana_v2_generate_messages_cpp)
```

but, "checker" is not getting printed.
This means, there is still some problem with the callback function.
please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213446/subscribing-to-custom-message-type/) by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
Have you had a look on rqt_graph like I wrote in the answer? Are the nodes connected by topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add the old package as dependency to your new package.

Inside the `CMakeLists.txt` and as run and build dependency in `package.xml`

And in the Callback you need your `const <package>::<message>::ConstPtr &msg`

CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   ... 
   your_old_package
)
```

package.xml:

```
   <run_depend>your_old_package</run_depend>
   <build_depend>your_old_package</build_depend>
```

I guess you are also missing to link your node inside CMakeLists.txt with roscpp by:

```
add_executable(<executable_name> <dependencies>)
target_link_libraries(<executable_name> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Have you checked `rqt_graph` if the topics are connected?

(deselect hide checkboxes to see unconnected topics rectangular boxes)

If not you might need to create a launchfile with remap:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

Have you checked that the publisher is really publishing?

`rostopic echo /mycustomtopic`

alternatively you could try to publish with rostopic

`rostopic pub /mycustomtopic package/MessageType` `<press tab twice (auto completion)>`

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-12**:
void chatterCallback(const rectified_imageConstPtr &msg)
is my callback function..
and I got the following error message:

/home/krish/architecture_ws/src/compute_disparity/src/hsvgmmN.cpp:116:28: error: ‘rectified_imageConstPtr’ does not name a type

I have the rectified_image.msg as my custom

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-12**:
Sorry messed something up, just checked back one of my own callbacks.

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-12**:
that also did not work! :(

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-07-13**:
Please post the function signature that doesn't work.

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
void chatterCallback(const swahana_v2::rectified_image::ConstPtr &msg){
std::cout << "checker" << std::endl;
}

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
Is it a typo?
chattercallback -> chatterCallback
(in your line above you write it with lower case letters and here you do camelcase)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-07-13**:
Please also always provide the compiler message.

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
Linking CXX executable /home/krish/architecture_ws/devel/lib/compute_disparity/hsvgmmN
CMakeFiles/hsvgmmN.dir/src/hsvgmmN.cpp.o: In function `ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe<swahana_v2::rectified_image_std::allocator<void > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocato

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-07-13**:
The comment length is limited, so your compiler message got cropped. Please post it in your original question with the edit function.

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
done! sorry for the inconvinience

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
do you have roscpp in your package dependencies?

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   roscpp
   your_old_package
)
```

because it does not find ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()' ...

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
Probably paste the non-commented lines of your CMakeLists.txt as well

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
yes, it is included

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
Actually I think your problem is somewhere else:

```
hsvgmmN.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15c): undefined reference to `ros::spin()'
```

Is this line inside your CMakeLists.txt?

```
target_link_libraries(<executable_name> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
NO!
I included it now, and it worked!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
So everything works now?

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
not exactly. please see my edited question

**Comment by [saikrishnagv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22351/saikrishnagv/) on 2015-07-13**:
no, they are not connected.
I did "rostopic list" to find out that "mycustomtopic" is being published